# range countdown to zero

Tags: python, range, zero

I am taking a beginner Python class and the instructor has asked us to countdown to zero without using recursion.  I am trying to use a for loop and range to do so, but he says we must include the zero.

I searched on the internet and on this website extensively but cannot find the answer to my question.  Is there a way I can get range to count down and include the zero at the end when it prints?

Edit:

```
def countDown2(start):
#Add your code here!
    for i in range(start, 0, -1):
        print(i)
```

Comment: The whole idea behind an instructor asking you to do it, is so that you can learn... researching for a solution *might* get you through this one assignment... but will hurt you in the long run. Attempt to answer it yourself and if you get stuck, post your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: @Rushikumar I wasn't looking for a solution but an answer to a particular way things work in python.  I forgot to include my work, but I edited my question and put it in there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function in Python has 3 parameters: `range([start], stop[, step])`.  If you want to count down instead of up, you can set the `step` to a negative number:

```
for i in range(5, -1, -1):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Right, that's what I did but it won't print the zero... OH wait!  You ended it at -1!  Thank you!

Comment: `range(start, stop)` does not include stop as one of it's values, so you must use `end + 1` (or -1) in your case if you wish to decrement

Answer (score 9):

As another option to @chrisz's answer, Python has a built-in [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function which produces an iterator in the reversed order.

```
start_inclusive = 4
for i in reversed(range(start_inclusive + 1)):
   print(i)
```

outputs

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

This can be sometimes easier to read, and for a well-written iterator (e.g. built-in range function), the performance should be the same.

Comment: I like this approach, especially since it will include `0`, might want to clarify that you must start at `start + 1` to include `start`

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard of reversed yet.  This is even better.  :)

Comment: Good idea @chrisz. The typical inclusive-start, exclusive-end style of iterators is more ambiguous when reversed.

Comment: I think this makes sense if e.g. indexing your list is easier this way (because it excludes len(my_list) ). You can also assign the original range to a variable so reversed(indexes_of_my_list) or similar reads nicely.

Answer (score 0):

In  the below code n_range doesn't need to be told to count up or down, it can just tell if the numbers ascend or descend through the power of math. A positive value divided by it's negative equivalent will output a -1 otherwise it outputs a 1.

```
def n_range(start, stop):
    return range(start, stop, int(abs(stop-start)/(stop-start)))
```

An input of 5, -1 will output

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```