# python3: Why iis the for loop in __init__ method not executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Field(object):                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    def __init__(self, states):                                                                                                                                                                                    
        self.states = states
        states = list(reversed(states))
        self.cells = {}
        print('debug1')
        for y in range(3, 0):
            for x in (1, 4):
                self.cells[(x, y)] = states.pop()
                print(self.cells[(x, y)])
                print('debug2')

my_field = Field('_XXOO_OX_')
print(my_field.cells)
```

the output is

> debug1
>
> {}

but I expect the dict my_field.cells is not empty, and there should be "debug2" printed out. It seems that the for loop in the `__init__` did not get executed.

Python version: 3.7.3

Comment: `for y in range(3, 0):` doesn't do what you think it does. When `range` is given 2 arguments the first is the start of the iteration and the second is the end.

Comment: Replace `for y in range(3, 0)` with `for y in range(3, 0, -1)`

Comment: To go from 2 to 0 you need `range(2, -1, -1)`.

Comment: [range-countdown-to-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539187/range-countdown-to-zero)

Comment: `print(list(range(3, 0)))` => `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a step while iterating from a higher number to lower number:

```
class Field(object):                                                                                                                                                                                               

    def __init__(self, states):                                                                                                                                                                                    
        self.states = states
        states = list(reversed(states))
        self.cells = {}
        print('debug1')
        for y in range(3, 0, -1):          # Here add -1 in your for loop range
            for x in (1, 4):
                self.cells[(x, y)] = states.pop()
                print(self.cells[(x, y)])
                print('debug2')

my_field = Field('_XXOO_OX_')
print(my_field.cells)
```